# SQLite command to insert current datetime not working through c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am trying to insert current date in my table from a c# application, i am doing this the following way:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename (column1,creation_date) VALUES ('abcd_" + (id) + "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But this throws error saying that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not a valid field.
I double checked the above query using sqlite manager plugin for firefox and it seems to work correctly.

P.S. - id in the above query is an int variable that is set by c# application.

Comment: try to strftime('%s','now') instead of current_timestamp. In SqlLite strftime get the UNIX time stamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is only valid in column definition.

As a expression, you can use `DATETIME('NOW')`. Try:

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename (column1,creation_date) VALUES ('abcd_" + (id) + "', DATETIME('NOW'));";
```

Comment: @LS_dev if you need to search according to the datetime what you do then if you insert DateTime as DATETIME('NOW') ?

Comment: SQLite has no date/time data type. But has built-in function to deal with some string formats (check [Time strings](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)). «The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"». So you may use `creation_date>='2013-10-10'` to find all date from today above, `DATE(create_date) BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-30'`to find date within those days, ...

Comment: @LS_dev....hey, your solution work's fine but the time it is showing is not proper though the date is shown correctly...i want it to show the time that is shown on my machine clock.

Comment: Probably local time/UTC mismatch. Try `SELECT DATETIME('NOW', 'LOCALTIME');` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(yourSqliteConnection))
{
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename (column1,creation_date) VALUES (?,?)";
cmd.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",string.Format("abcd_{0}",id));
cmd.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
cmd.CommandType= CommmandType.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**DateTime.Now.ToString("s")** means convert this datetime into **XSD** format. 
SQLite does not have a DateTime Format in its own. so everything you need is to convert it into a fixed format of TEXT and then insert and serach according to this format.

**XSD is a fixed format for DateTime. it does not change if format of DateTime Change.**

**Remember when you need to do a search (SELECT) command based on DateTime try to convert it as shown above before doing any operation in SQLite.**